# Amcharts can't correctly parse datetime from mysql

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, amcharts

I have this JSON data (chartData):

> [{"date":"2017-01-24 12:00:00","op":"678.283"},{"date":"2017-01-24
>   13:00:00","op":"616.854"},{"date":"2017-01-24
>   14:00:00","op":"611.969"},{"date":"2017-01-24
>   15:00:00","op":"602.912"},...

and display it by following code:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"dataProvider": chartData,
"categoryField": "date",
"dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "labelRotation": 60,               
},
"graphs": [ {
"valueField": "op"              
} ]
} );
```

I created format accorging to  https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/. The chart correctly parses days, but can't separate items in one day, so they are displayed as one vertical line, see 
[resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKfAp.png) Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) that represents the minimum time interval between each of your points. The default `minPeriod` is daily (`"DD"`) so you'll want to adjust that for your data, which appears to be hourly (`"hh"`) from your sample data.

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  // ..
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "hh",
    "labelRotation": 60         
  },
  // ..
} );
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7ef252adfa47e63931419ba59ca79d57?editors=0010)